# Mybatis query returns an empty set

Tags: java, null, mybatis

The result of SQL query is empty,However, the length of the list in the encapsulation result is 1.
And the element in the list is null,So What shall I do?

Comment: Let's look at your code

Comment: an simple query code,maybe caused by I used aggregate functions in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Do you check whether the name mapping between the field names and column name is true?
if field names are not same, you should write a `ResultMap` for name mapping manually.

Comment: That's right,now I delete the null field from the collection first, and then judge whether it is empty.But I wonder if there are any other solutions.